Trigger automation when row added to Data Extension (without external API)
I want to trigger an automation when a new row is added to a Data Extension.
I can trigger it via the API, but building this trigger inside the Marketing Cloud would be much better because otherwise, we should call this automation whenever and wherever a new record is added to the Data Extension from outside and that creates a lot of code for the Web team.

You can do this by:

Create one DE called "Last Triggered Record". The goal of this one is to keep the date of the most recent record. It should only have 1 date field.
Create another DE called "New Records", that will just detect if new records are to be added.

In the Automation:

Set the Automation to run hourly/as frequently as you want to check for new records
In the first Activity, have a SQL Query that targets New Records (with Overwrite data action), with CREATED_DATE > GETDATE() (assuming your final target DE has a Created_Date field)
The second step, should be a validation step: if New Records is empty, stop the automation; otherwise continue
After validation, update the Last Triggered Record DE (select max(created_date) ...)
As of here, you can perform the activities you intended for your Automation

Hope this helps!

Thank you for the workaround solution. But this is also a scheduled automation that behaves like a triggered one. Also, my target DE does not have a Create_Date field now but that can be added, but I am looking for a solution that is really trigger-based.

Then I think the only way to do it is with a Journey that starts with a Salesforce event, I don't know a way to do what you are trying with a DE in SFMC :(
